# How to generate random numbers only on session change

Tags: jsp, session, random

Here I have used JSP to generate random numbers and calculate their sum and average. I haven't used sessions. But how can I implement session such that new random numbers generated only at new sessions and random numbers generated in the first session is retained throughout even with page refresh.

Here's the code

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Random"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Working Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Experiment</h1>
        <%
            Date createTime = new Date(session.getCreationTime());
            Date lastAccessTime = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());

            int r = 25, c = 5, n;
            double t=0;
            int i=0,j=0;
            double num[][] = new double[27][5];
            Random ran = new Random();
            out.print("<table border='1px'>");
            out.print("<tr><th>Trial-1</th><th>Trial-2</th><th>Trial-3</th><th>Horizontal Sum</th><th>Horizontal Average</th></tr>");
            for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
                t=0;
                out.print("<tr>");
                for(j=0;j<c-2;j++) {
                    n = ran.nextInt(10-1+1)+1;
                    num[i][j]=n;
                    t = t+ n;
                    out.print("<td>"+ n +"</td>");
                }
                num[i][3]=t;
                num[i][4]=t/3;
                out.print("<td>"+ t +"</td> "+ "<td>"+ t/3+"</td> ");
                out.println("</tr>");
            }
            for(i=0;i<c;i++) {
                t=0;
                for(j=0;j<r;j++) {
                    t = t + num[j][i];
                }
                num[j][i]=t;
                num[j+1][i]=t/25;
            }
            for(i=25;i<27;i++) {
                out.print("<tr>");
                if(i==25)
                    out.print("<th colspan='3'>Vertical Sum</th>");
                if(i==26)
                    out.print("<th colspan='3'>Vertical Average</th>");
                for(j=3;j<c;j++) {
                    out.print("<td>"+ num[i][j]+"</td>");
                }
                out.println();
                out.print("</tr>");
            }
            out.print("</table>");
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: I converted the session time to millisecond and fed it as a seed to the Random class. If anyone wants to know how it was done in the future.

Comment: HttpSession has an isNew()  method. Why don't you use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to check and set some session attribute to determine if the session is new or not.  Something like:

```
<%
String flag = (String)session.getAttribute("randomNumbersWereGenerated");
if(flag==null)
{
  //this is a new session 
  //since the flag is not yet set
  generateRandomNumbers(); //pseudo-code
  session.setAttribute("randomNumbersWereGenerated", "true");
}
else
{
   retrieveAndUseRandomNumbersFromSession(); //pseudo-code
}
%>
```

It also sounds like you want to save the random numbers into the session.  For that purpose you might want to put them into a datatype like a List/LinkedList rather than an array.

So in generating the random numbers:

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
list.add(...);
...
session.setAttribute("randomNumsList", list);
```

In retrieving them from the session:

```
LinkedList list = (LinkedList)session.getAttribute("randomNumsList");
```

Comment: '<form action="index.jsp">
            <input type="hidden" name="ns" id="ns" value="new" >
            <input type="submit" value="New Session">
            <% 
                String temp = (String)request.getParameter("ns");
                if(temp=="new") {
                    out.println("New Session started");
                    session.invalidate();
                }
            %>
        </form>' 

I tried this but the if condition always fail eventhough both have the strings "new" on clicking the button.

Comment: @SamPro `==` is not correct for string comparison in Java. In java use `.equals()` and its best to put the dot on the object that can never be null to avoid a NullPointerException.  So your `if(temp=="new")` becomes `if("new".equals(temp))`  or `if(temp!=null && temp.equals("new"))`

Comment: HttpSession has an isNew() method. Why don't you use that?

Comment: @developerwjk thank you I follow that comment and it worked. Didnt need a list.